# Query for a sum function

Tags: sql, azure

So hey guys...

I have this one problem, I need to include to SUM aggregate function in my query but I want it to be somewhere specific in the query result. The easiest would be for you to look at the picture and maybe you will know what I mean and what I want to achieve.

I want a temporary field (eg. SUM) which I can join on the end -

```
sum(l.cijenaKupovna) as SUM
```

code:

```
SELECT n.datum, n.IdNarudzbe, l.naziv, l.proizvodac, z.prezime, d.naziv, l.cijenaKupovna, sum(l.cijenaKupovna) from narudzbe n
    JOIN lijekovi_has_narudzbe ln ON ln.IdNarudzbe=n.IdNarudzbe
    JOIN lijekovi l ON ln.serijskiBroj = l.serijskiBroj
    JOIN dobavljaci d ON d.IdDobavljac = n.IdDobavljac
    JOIN zaposlenici z ON z.OIB = n.OIB
    GROUP BY 2;
```

I get this ERROR : Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Is this what Im asking even possible? :D
[image]

Comment: I legitimately have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: so what's stopping you from adding a `sum(l.cijenaKupovna)` at the end of your field list? of course you'll also need a `group by` clause to make that sum actually seful.

Comment: this is like an "receipt" so I want to SUM the last column (cijenaKupovna) and have it as a result in a seperate column on the bottom

Comment: I get this msg: Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

And I group by 2 (the ID)

Comment: Can you put your error and your query using SUM?

Comment: I updated my question with error and code

Comment: You need to put in GROUP BY all columns not in SUM.

Comment: Doesn't work... still the same error. I guess there must be done something different some OUTER JOIN, but I dont know how to do it

Comment: @user3732071 `OUTER JOIN` won't solve the problem. You need to understand a little bit about how `GROUP BY` works. As Mihai said, it should be `... GROUP BY n.datum, n.IdNarudzbe, l.naziv, l.proizvodac, z.prezime, d.naziv, l.cijenaKupovna`

Comment: But then I just get the same number as in the previous column (l.cijenaKupovna) - I want to sum all those numbers

Comment: To Win's point you need to GROUP by but exclude l.cijenaKupovna as that is your aggregated value.

Answer (score 1):

Your GROUP BY clause needs to contain every columns that you are querying except the one used for the SUM.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'lijekovi.cijenaKupovna' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It makes no sense to have [l.cijenaKupovna] in the SELECT and a SUM on this same column. If you want a sum you need to remove this column from the select statement and keep only the SUM on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [GROUP BY](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php) those fields that you are not aggregating:

```
SELECT n.datum, n.IdNarudzbe, l.naziv, l.proizvodac, z.prezime, d.naziv, l.cijenaKupovna, sum(l.cijenaKupovna) from narudzbe n
JOIN lijekovi_has_narudzbe ln ON ln.IdNarudzbe=n.IdNarudzbe
JOIN lijekovi l ON ln.serijskiBroj = l.serijskiBroj
JOIN dobavljaci d ON d.IdDobavljac = n.IdDobavljac
JOIN zaposlenici z ON z.OIB = n.OIB
GROUP BY n.datum, n.IdNarudzbe, l.naziv, l.proizvodac, z.prezime, d.naziv
```

As you noted in your comment, however, when you pull in your aggregated value, `l.cijenaKupovna`, in your GROUP BY you will get the same number in your last two fields. Technically speaking when you do this you are still `SUM`-ing your lines, but you are only performing your sum at each individual row. When you remove `l.cijenaKupovna`from your group by, however, you will `SUM` by everything but this column (which is what you want).

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'lijekovi.cijenaKupovna' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: Azure SQL, dunno what engine is that?

Comment: Actually that is the engine... I'm not familiar with Azure but it should follow basic ANSI SQL... I'm thinking that one of your joins is causing you issues. Try dropping them one by one until the error message goes away in order to trace the problem. Ultimately, your query is telling you that it doesn't recognize what is in the SUM function...

Answer (score 1):

Try with analytic way:

```
SELECT n.datum, n.IdNarudzbe, l.naziv, l.proizvodac, z.prezime, d.naziv, l.cijenaKupovna, sum(l.cijenaKupovna) over() from narudzbe n
    JOIN lijekovi_has_narudzbe ln ON ln.IdNarudzbe=n.IdNarudzbe
    JOIN lijekovi l ON ln.serijskiBroj = l.serijskiBroj
    JOIN dobavljaci d ON d.IdDobavljac = n.IdDobavljac
    JOIN zaposlenici z ON z.OIB = n.OIB
```

If you only want to show one value you can do this:

```
SELECT n.datum, n.IdNarudzbe, l.naziv, l.proizvodac, z.prezime, d.naziv, l.cijenaKupovna, 
case when rownum = 1 then sum(l.cijenaKupovna) over() else null end case from narudzbe n
JOIN lijekovi_has_narudzbe ln ON ln.IdNarudzbe=n.IdNarudzbe
JOIN lijekovi l ON ln.serijskiBroj = l.serijskiBroj
JOIN dobavljaci d ON d.IdDobavljac = n.IdDobavljac
JOIN zaposlenici z ON z.OIB = n.OIB
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Yes this works! However, how can I have only one SUM beneath all, for example in the 4th (blank) row as I pictured on the image?

Comment: @user3732071 I edit my post, I hope that is you are looking for